# Docker error: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 127)

Tags: database, bash, docker, nosql, containers

For some reason, I can't make a docker container. I created a file (create-container.sh) containing docker container details:

```
docker run \ 
  -d \
  --name people-db \
  --mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)",dst="/code" \
  mongo
```

Now when I try to type in terminal to run the container:

> bash docker_scripts/create-container.sh

This is the error in full when I try to process the above command:

> docker: failed to register layer: Error processing tar file(exit status 127): Inconsistency detected by ld.so: ../sysdeps/x86_64/dl-machine.h: 547: elf_machine_rela_relative: Assertion `ELFW(R_TYPE) (reloc->r_info) == R_X86_64_RELATIVE' failed!

I've been instructed to load file too:

> load('code/db/setup.js')

But it's also giving an error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `'code/db/setup.js''

Anyone have any ideas of what is wrong?

Comment: I was able to run this script without issue. I would look more into that 127 error. This might be and issue with your docker install rather than your script.